# Assigning an int to a struct object without using unsafe

Tags: c#, structure, unsafe

I have a struct definition in c# as follows

```
public struct test                                                                                  
{
    byte   SetCommonPOP;
    byte   SetCommonSVP;
    byte   SetCommonUHDP;
    byte   SetCommonMHDP;
};
```

How do I assign an int y to an object x of this structure without having to use unsafe?

Comment: How would you want the `int` to be interpreted? Different endianness systems could convert in different ways.

Comment: Both an int and the struct object takes 4 bytes. Assuming that the first member takes up the LSB and the fourth the MSB

Comment: That would be big Endian right? Sorry, but I always get confused.

Comment: I believe that's little-endian, actually: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness Anyway, that's why my answer makes it explicit - you can always change it round :)

Comment: That would be little-endian. I remember it by [the story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Etymology) that is the source of the "endian" words: those who start with the little end of the soft-boiled eggs are little-endian, those who start with the big end are big-endian. It's confusing because big-endian isn't when you end with the big values, but when you start with the "big end".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write a custom conversion operator:

```
public struct Test
{
    private readonly byte pop;
    private readonly byte svp;
    private readonly byte uhdp;
    private readonly byte mhdp;

    // TODO: Properties to return the above

    public Test(byte pop, byte svp, byte uhdp, byte mhdp)
    {
        this.pop = pop;
        this.svp = svp;
        this.uhdp = uhdp;
        this.mhdp = mhdp;
    }

    public static implicit operator Test(int value)
    {
        // Working from most significant to least significant bits...
        byte mhdp = (byte) ((value >> 0) & 0xff);
        byte uhdp = (byte) ((value >> 8) & 0xff);
        byte svp = (byte) ((value >> 16) & 0xff);
        byte pop = (byte) ((value >> 24) & 0xff);
        return new Test(pop, svp, uhdp, mhdp);
    }
}
```

Personally I'd prefer a static `FromInt32` method instead of an implicit operator, but that's your call. It's very possible that you don't need all the `& 0xff` parts in the conversion - and I wouldn't bother with them if you were using a `uint` instead of an `int`. Extracting parts of a signed integer just makes me twitchy, and this is possibly overcompensation. Another alternative would be a cast of `value` to a `uint` as a local variable to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an explicit struct layout:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Test
{
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public readonly byte pop;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public readonly byte svp;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public readonly byte uhdp;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public readonly byte mhdp;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private int value;

    public static Test FromInt32(int value)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        test.value = value;
        return test;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so here, it is treated like a union with value member occupying the same space as the first 4 members. Right?

Comment: Should work too I guess. Only thing I dont want to alter the struct definition. Thanks anyways